# $(window).load fires too quickly in IE with asynchronous js libs

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, asynchronous, window-load

I have some serious problem with getting asynchronously some js libs and executing them in `$(window).load` in IE

all works in other browsers of course

so the problem is, that I'm doing something like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var scr1 = document.createElement('script'); 
 scr1.type = 'text/javascript'; 
 scr1.src = 'some_lib.js'; 
 $('BODY').prepend(scr1); 
</script>
```

Just before `</body>` and use `$(window).load` method in html above it to operate on some plugins in `some_lib.js`, but it all happens to fast in IE, probable because of that asynchronous lib including, and I get an error, that method is not available for the element.

Is there any chance of maybe modyfying `$(window).load` method so I still could use it in the same way for every browser ?

Comment: Maybe you should be looking into a library like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: which specific version of jQuery are you using? is it 1.8.0?

Comment: 1.6.1, tried to use 1.8.1 instead but no effect

Comment: have you tried with `$(window).ready();` or `$(document).ready();`

Comment: yes, ready() events will run just after DOM is loaded, so even earlier than `$(window).load();`

Comment: even better - when I click on link to page which contains that code, I get an error, when I press f5 everything works fine (?)
furthermore, putting `setTimeout` in like this `$(window).load(setTimeout(function(){}, 1000))` makes it work (cause script waits a little bit longer), but it's not a solution at all

Comment: Is there a reason you dynamically load the script(s) instead of simply using script tags?  Because they are not embedded in the page they are not required for `.load()` to execute.  If they were then they would be - that's the problem you're facing.

Comment: on our system we've developed widgets and plugins which have their own js libraries and it is important to load them only in places/pages that require them.
Furthermore, in some pages we use 10 instances of the same plugin (which has its own templates where I could simply put those `script` tags, but then those libs would be multiply downloaded by the browser)

Answer (score 1):

Any code that you have in the `window.load()` call must be placed in a function (called `onLoad` in this example).

Every time you have a script that you dynamically load, increment a counter.  Also include something to decrement that counter...

```
src1.onload = function() { counter--; onLoad(); }
```

Then in 'onLoad' have the first line...

```
if (counter > 0) return;
```

That means that `onLoad` will fire at `window.load` and after every script is loaded, but will only execute when it's all loaded.

It's scrappy, but it will solve your problem.

Comment: quite interesting, will try it tomorrow ;)

Comment: It's similar to counting the images on a page and performing some action when they are all loaded, which is a common thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really described the reason you need to load these libraries asynchronously.  Third party libraries often have "on script load" functionality that you can define before the script is loaded.  If you need to load multiple libraries before you can execute your code, you may have to either 1. fire up some code every time a library is loaded to test to see if all libraries required are loaded and then fire off you code 2. for every library, create a jQuery promise/deferred to get resolved when that library is loaded and use `$.when(`*promises*`).done(`*function/code*`)` to test and run the code whenever a particular set is loaded, or 3. rewrite to use RequireJS.   If these libraries are YOUR code, well, you may have to add start up code to your libraries anyway; It might be a good time to learn RequireJS.

I wish I could recommend further, but learning the basics behind RequireJS has always been on my todo list, but it hasn't been done;  I just know of people here successfully using it.  If that seems like too much trouble, I'd consider some variant of option 2.  If you don't know what jQuery would be used eh... you may be stuck with option 1 or 3.

Edit:

Of course, that's not to say that jQuery has got the only promise library, I just often recommend using promises in some form for these kind of things..

Archer's technique looks interesting, I just don't know how reliable it is (it might be quite reliable, I just would like to see proof/documentation).  You could combine that with option 2 also, quite well, if you want to short-cut execution for some things while leaving others to be dealt asynchronously and if those script onload methods really work as expected.

Comment: 90% of libraries are mine, basically the mechanism I've wanted to implement should be as easy to use as possible (rest of the developers should just run some widgets' method which is used to include new library, and in plugins' html put some js code like `$(window).load(function(){})` - and this works perfectly everywhere, but not in IE)

Comment: Well, whatever you do, you can always add a wrapper and make things easier for the developers.  Maybe even write some code to do it all in one step, as in `$("#widgetSelector").widgetScript("/some/script/src.js").done(function(){ ... choose widget and run code with it, etc...});`.  There are a lot of possibilities.

Comment: (`widgetScript` would be something you'd have to write, just to be clear)